# How many keybindings does Emacs have

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I use Emacs for few years, learning keybinding from time to time.  Often, I forget they after a short time.  Now I've started to learn keybindings with Anki.  And it raised an interesting question: how many keybindings does Emacs have?

By keybinding I mean full chain that calls specific function.  I know that Emacs have a huge number of major and minor mode.  So, how one can get full list of bindings in specific mode?

And, by the way, how many keybindings does Org-mode have?

Comment: https://vimeo.com/77451201#t=78

Comment: Define "Emacs". Emacs can have as many or as few key bindings as you like.

Comment: How many do _you_ want there to be?

Comment: You say you've used Emacs a few years?  Well, learn only 10 keybindings a day, consistently, and in _another_ few years you'll know them all!

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>C-h b</kbd> shows the list of all keybindings in sections.

In Fundamental mode, the help buffer contains about 1700 lines (<kbd>C-u M-=</kbd>).  Not all of them are bindings, but it is not very important.

In Org-mode, the help buffer contains more than 2000 lines.  But keybindings there are very unusual.  As in the documentation, <kbd>C-c</kbd> "is a very busy key" which has many functions in different contexts.  Another example, <kbd>C-c down</kbd> calls `org-shiftdown` function, the behaviour of which depends on context.

To get the number of keybindings that depend on context is not so simple as it seems.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, Emacs's keybindings vary depending on the current
major-mode, the active minor-modes, and sometimes even the location of
point in the buffer.

"C-h b", `describe-bindings` will bring up a list of available
keybindings in the current buffer.  It includes global keybindings,
which are not mode-specific.  But the bindings
are divided into sections for the mode that defines them.  In recent
Emacs versions, the buffer is presented in `outline-minor-mode`, so
you can fold the different sections in order to ease browsing, a
significant improvement given the number of bindings available.

Another way to get specific information about the active modes in a
buffer (including the keybindings they provide) is "C-h m",
`describe-mode`.  However, the information provided by this command
depends on the documentation written for each mode.  So it might not
be as comprehensive or thorough as `describe-bindings`.

Since you mention forgetting bindings, you might enjoy the `which-key`
package if you're not already aware of it.  It shows available
bindings whenever you enter a prefix key and pause before entering the
next key in the sequence.  So if you press "C-c" and wait a moment, it will show you all
the available keybindings that start with that prefix in the current
buffer (same for "C-x", "C-h", "M-g", "M-s", etc.).  Unlike
`describe-bindings`, you don't have to press any extra keys to see the
bindings, and you don't have to browse and manage a separate "*Help*"
buffer and window.  You simply press the next key in the sequence, and it gets
out of your way.  It also includes a command to show top-level
bindings (those that don't start with a prefix key).  There are some
other packages that do this, but `which-key` appears to be the most
popular.

I notice the body of your question seems more specific than the title.
The title asks how many keys "does Emacs have", and the body seems
more about how many bindings are available in a given mode.

But this
got me wondering about it myself.  I did some playing around with
`ripgrep` in a shell and came up with the following attempt to roughly
approximate the total number of keybindings in Emacs:

```
KeyBindFuncs="global-set-key local-set-key define-key org-defkey"
for func in $KeyBindFuncs; do rg -g *.el "^[^;]*\($func "; done | wc -l
```

This searches recursively through all elisp files within the current
directory tree and counts all lines that appear to call one of the
listed keybinding functions.  It excludes commented lines, since
those wouldn't be evaluated.

Caveats:

- It only counts uses of the functions `global-set-key`,
  `local-set-key`, `define-key`, and `org-defkey`.  The latter is what
  `org-mode` uses to set most of its keybindings.  There are other
  ways one could set a keybinding, perhaps other specialized commands.
  It could even be done by directly manipulating a keymap list.  But I
  believe the first three functions in the list are the ones most
  commonly used.
- Where those function-calls are repeated, such as when used in a
  macro that's called several times or in a `dolist` form that defines
  a list of keybindings, the occurence of the keybinding function is
  only counted the one time that it appears in the text, rather than
  the many times it is actually being called.
- This count will include bindings to keymaps (prefix-keys).  However,
  the number of prefix keys counted is likely to be smaller than
  the number of bindings left uncounted due to the reasons listed
  above.
- Emacs consists of a lot of packages.  Some of them may not be in
  wide use anymore, but they continue to be included in Emacs because
  someone somewhere is still relying on them.  Those packages--when
  they're actually used--also create keybindings.  But their
  keybindings are only enabled when they're loaded and a particular
  keymap is active.  So even though Emacs *has* a lot of keybinding
  definitions, most of the time only a small fraction of those
  keybindings are set, and an even smaller fraction are available at a
  given moment.

  So this is not any sort of indication of how many keybindings an
  Emacs user needs to memorize.  The only keybindings you need to
  memorize are the ones you actually use.

That said, running the above command lines from the root of
the current Emacs master branch returns:

```
8618
```

Good grief, that's a lot of keybindings!

If we filter the list to only include lines starting with
"lisp/org/" (the subdirectory where org-mode's files go), the result
is:

```
526
```

I think those are pretty close to the actual number of defined
keybindings in the whole of Emacs and in org-mode, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then `S-TAB` (by default) at top level shows you all possible key bindings in the current context, regardless of what (modes etc.) might be responsible for those bindings.

It shows the key bindings as completion candidates, in buffer `*Completions*`, for [key completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion).

And as always in `icicle-mode`, the current *number of completion candidates* is shown in the mode-line of buffer `*Completions*`. E.g., `394 candidates`. So without any filtering, this number is the number of all key bindings available in the current context. This is available any time, in any context (and not just at top-level, but also following prefix keys).

See [Icicles - Completions Display](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completions_Display) for description and screenshot.